# Appsettings.json based on environments doesn't load

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0

I want to read appsettings.json then replace the keys based on each environment. After a lot of research I feel clueless, I read other posts about something similar but the solutions provided didn't help, the implementation in Program.cs should work in theory but the application keeps using just appsettings.json.

Program.cs

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
                {

                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

        public static string Environment
        {
            get
            {
                string environmentName;
                #if DEBUG
                environmentName = "Development";
                #elif RELEASE
                environmentName = "Test";
                #endif
                return environmentName;
            }
        }
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myconn": "connection"
  }
}
```

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myconn": "connectionDev"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myconn": "connectionDev"
  }
}
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49416/",
      "sslPort": 44368
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express Test": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Test"
      }
    },
    "WICAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Need to check this because you don't say, but do you have the environment variable set up in the operating system?  For example on your dev machine, do you have : ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

Comment: Yes, I created the variable  using the command  `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"`, but based on my code it wouldn't affect?

Answer (score 2):

- Firstly you need to create `launchSettings.json` in `Properties`

[image]

With content some thing like this. Update follow your business.

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/test",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51572/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "test.Web.Local": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost/test",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51572/"
    },
    "test.Web.Staging": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51572/"
    },
    "test.Web.RC": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "ReleaseCandidate"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51572/"
    },
    "test.Web.Prod": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51572/"
    }
  }
}
```

- Your json file

[image]

- In startup file you can use

  services.Configure(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
- When run debug choose `env` you want run

Hope to help you.

Comment: Yes, I have launchSettings.json. I edited my post to show how it looks like.  Whe I add this `services.Configure(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));` in `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` it gives me this error `'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Configure' and the best extension method overload 'WebHostBuilderExtensions.Configure(IWebHostBuilder, Action<IApplicationBuilder>)' requires a receiver of type 'IWebHostBuilder'`

Comment: I see, You are using netcore 3.x or higher. I can try `configuration.GetSection("name_in_json_config_file").Get<Object_to_parse>();`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configuration.getsection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core actually does that for you. There's no need to do anything. Leave `Program.cs` as default:

```cs
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

The general configuration must be on `appsettings.json` and just write the configs you want to override from `appsettings.json` in your `appsettings.{env}.json` file, being `{env}` the name of the environment, eg:

appsettings.json

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myconn": "connection"
  }
}
```

appsettings.Development.json

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myconn": "connectionDev"
  }
}
```